# Selenium - check if element is present else check if another element is present (in python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

I'm writing a program that scrapes courses from my schools website and i'm trying to check what element is present after I click on the search button.

If 'id1' is present then that means the course is not available and the next course needs to be searched, else if 'id2' is present then that means the course is available so scrape it and search the next course.

This is what I have at the moment but it's not working. I've tired using webdriverwait with conditional statements but I couldn't get it to work either. So how can I solve this?

```
while(i < len(courseNumList)):
   self.clearAndSearch(courseNumList[i], coursePrefixList[i])

   if(len(self.driver.find_elements_by_id('id1')) > 0):
      i = i + 1
      continue
   self.scrapeAndModifySearch(courses, INDEX_NAME, TYPE_NAME)
      i = i + 1
```

scrapeAndModifySearch():

```
def scrapeAndModifySearch(self, courses, esindex, estypename):
   self.getCourses(courses, esindex, estypename)
   self.modifySearch()
```

getCourses():

```
def getCourses(self, courses, INDEX_N, TYPE_N):
   course = {}

   try:
      element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id2'))
      WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(element_present)
   except TimeoutException:
      print ("Loading took too much time!")

   classSectionsFound = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('id2').text
```

Comment: The element might be presence just not visible yet, have you tried 'self.driver.find_element_by_id('id1').is_Displayed()'?

Comment: You need to give more details about *it's not working*. What happens? and if you get an exception you need to add the stack trace.

Comment: The error I'm getting is: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath 'id2'

Comment: I think what is happening is that when I click search on the webpage, the element id2 isn't found because the search wasn't executed when it was clicked. And I just tried using is_Displayed() but the same thing is happening.

Comment: The code you provided won't produce this error. Please add the relevant code.

Comment: This is the code that's giving me that error

Comment: `find_elements_*` won't throw `NoSuchElementException`. The exception occurs in `clearAndSearch()` or `scrapeAndModifySearch()` or some other place not in the code snippet.

Comment: scrapeAndModifySearch() is giving me that error

Comment: To avoid repeated questions for more information, in the future it would be helpful if you post the full stack trace when you ask a question about an error. Even if you don't think it's relevant. Too much information is better than not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've mixed up your locators. That last line should be:

```
   classSectionsFound = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id2').text
```

'id2' is not valid xpath (at least not for a HTML doc).